# Checking Table exists before inserting php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to check if a table exists before entering the data into it. I am trying `mysql_query` and getting errors that I should be using mysqli, but it does not seem to be working for me.

This is my code so far:

```
$AllData = $_POST["table"];
foreach ($AllData as $sigleData) {
    $table = $sigleData['name'];
    $columns = implode(", ", $sigleData['columns']);
    $columnData = implode(" ',' ", $sigleData['data']);

    // Insert into database tuple data      
    $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " ( " . $columns . ") VALUES( '" . $columnData . "')";


    if ($dbConnectionT->query($sqlQuery) == TRUE) {
        echo "database updated";
        echo "</br>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: I dont see in your code that you are trying to check if the table exists as you say

Comment: Are you sure it's not a Notice telling you to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), because PHP's `mysql` class is deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to check `table` exists or not using this custom function  and then `insert` row to your db.

```
function check_table_exist($table){
    global $dbConnection; // see here global connection variable
    $sql = "SHOW tables LIKE '".$table."'";
    $res = $dbConnection->query($sql);
    return ($res->num_rows > 0);
}
```

#check first table exists or not

```
if(check_table_exists($table)){
 $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " ( " . $columns . ") VALUES( '" . $columnData . "')";
 //do other stuff........
}else{
    echo "Table Not Exists";
    die('Going Out');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Table name is accepted as POST parameter, seriously !! - bad practice.
You can do various check to table existence like

```
DESC tbl_name;
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;
SHOW TABLES like 'tbl_name';
```